# Open Source C# Plugin Provider Harnes (Console App or Windows Service)

Tags: c#, plugins, open-source

### My Goal

I'm looking for a Good C# Provider model library that automatically re-loads updated Provider DLL's and keeps running.

### My Current (Old) Solution

I have an old SnapIn/Plugin component harness which I use to provide plugin capabilities to web apps or windows services. In the past I have used it to read/write HTTP requests every 10 minutes or watch for file changes and load in data files.

I simply have a IPlugIn with life cyle methods such as Initialize, Start,Stop

I also have base implementations such as Interval (Fire ever N seconds) or File Watcher do do something when a file changes.

### The goal I want to achieve with my current system (my goal)

I want to be able to:

- Alter code
- re-compile
- Copy the DLL to the Windows Serviced folder
- And finally have the DLL automatically load, initialize and execute

### Options

1. Write some sort of code to automatically unload old DLL and load in new DLL
   or
2. Find an Open Source Plugin/Provider library that will achieve my goal

### Examples of Current Code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// All SnapIn/Provider implement this interface
    /// </summary>
    public interface ISnapIn
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Configuration information for the SnapIn.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config">The config.</param>
        void SetConfig(SnapInConfigurationSnapInDo config);

        /// <summary>
        /// Unique SnapIn ID
        /// </summary>
        string Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Description SnapIn.
        /// </summary>
        string Description { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Life-Cycle State
        /// </summary>
        SnapInStateType State { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the snapin.
        /// </summary>
        void Initialize(SnapInManager manager, NameValueDictionary parameters);

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts this snapin
        /// </summary>
        void Start();

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops this snpin.
        /// </summary>
        void Stop();
    }
```

.

```
    public abstract class FileWatchSnapIn : BaseSnapIn
    {
        // *********************************************************************************
        // Properties
        // *********************************************************************************

        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string Filter { get; set; }

        protected FileSystemWatcher Watcher { get; set; }
        // ...     
    }
```

.

```
    public abstract class IntervalSnapIn : BaseSnapIn
    {
        // *********************************************************************************
        // Properties
        // *********************************************************************************

        protected Timer Timer { get; set; }

        protected long Interval { get; set; }

        protected bool FireIntervalTaskOnStart { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I have just been Reading about MEF, I'm wondering if others would agree that MEF may be the answer to my plugin architecture requirements

Comment: As far as I know, MEF uses Assembly.Load (or a variation) to load assemblies, so it won't be possible to unload the assembly once it is loaded, making it somehow not suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's MAF framework will allow you to unload app domains if you set things up correctly.
In fact the most common scenario is to load each add-in into a separate app domain.

In essence, you can select the isolation level for an add-in to control this.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200%28v=vs.100%29.aspx